# Failed to instantiate module when minifying javascript files in AngularJS app with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: angularjs, minify

When I try to minify this controller:

```
Controller2.$inject = ['$scope', 'TestService'];

angular.module('app.controllers')
    .controller('TestController', Controller2);

function Controller2($scope, TestService) {
    $scope.teste = 'right!';
}
```

I have this module file:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('app', ['app.controllers', 'app.services', 'socialbase.sweetAlert', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
    angular.module('app.controllers', []);
    angular.module('app.services', []);
})();
```

and my HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="TestController" class="container-fluid" style="padding-top: 25px;">
        {{teste}}
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I minify it, it gives me this error:

```
Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/nomod?p0=app
```

If I don't minify the javascript files, it works normally.

Comment: In your bundle did you use `IncludeDirectory` and enabled `searchSubdirectories`? if yes could you show your folder structure of the app

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject it on the instance. Try it this way

```
var Controller2 = function($scope, TestService) {
    $scope.teste = 'right!';
}
Controller2.$inject = ['$scope', 'TestService'];
angular.module('app.controllers')
    .controller('TestController', Controller2);
```

Comment: @William same as the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#-inject-property-annotation. Guess u need to setup a plunkr

Comment: Is it possible to minify on plunkr? I have an error only when I try to minify the javascript files.

Comment: @William No you can't, but it will give a better overview of your solution. Also, esiier to take down locally and minify if the issue is not found